# Java script weight-change while typing

Tags: javascript, html, function, text

Hello I created a variable font and I want to make it useable in a way, that when you are typing on a website it slowly increases its weight. with the code I have right now though, it only jumps to full weight and does't undergo all the other stages and I kind of don't know how to fix it since I'm new to java script and programming. Thank you in advance!!!

```
<p id="testarea" contentEditable="true">
Type your text here
</p>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">uncensour</button>

<script>



document.getElementById("testarea").onchange = function() {myFunction()}
document.getElementById("testarea").addEventListener("input", myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "900";
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "101";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

```js
document.getElementById("testarea").onchange = function() {myFunction()}
document.getElementById("testarea").addEventListener("input", myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "900";
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("testarea").style.fontWeight = "101";
}
```

```html
<input type="textarea" id="testarea" contentEditable="true">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">uncensour</button>
```